# Does Adobe reader have any "fit to print" options?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I have a PDF file that contains a number of long columns.  No chance these will fit on an 8.5x11" page, even in landscape, without some wrapping issues.

Excel has a fit to print option whereby the final product is shrunk to fit the width of the page.  The fonts can get small but you do end up with a document that won't wrap when it's printed out.  Is there something similar I can do for PDFs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

On every version of Adobe Reader when you go to print a pdf there is this option which does exactly what you're asking:

[image]

If it is missing then you need to [update your copy of Adobe Reader](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you print in Adobe Reader, in the print screen go down to the section labeled as **Page Handling**. The option *Page Scaling* will be a dropdown menu, choose "Fit to Printable Area".